# Should I use a comma in this sentence

Tags: commas

Should I use a comma before *can*

> As a further research the relation of whether a firm has adopted IT framework and the number of failed IT investment projects**,** can be empirically examined.

Comment: YACQ !!! Yet another comma question. Which shouldn't be asked here, either.

Comment: Can the comma.  But put one after the initial qualifying clause.

Comment: The sentence isn’t grammatical, and so worrying about its punctuation just tries to paint lipstick on a pig, as the saying goes.

Comment: I think I sort of understand what it's intending to ask, but man that's an awkward approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [As a further research] the relation of [whether a firm has adopted IT framework] and [the number of failed IT investment projects] can be [empirically examined].

This sentence can be simplified as "The relation of A and B can be C." A comma after B would be ungrammatical. The answer to your question is that, no, that comma is not appropriate.

After "research," however, a comma is acceptable and recommended.

There are other syntactical errors in your sentence. A cleaned up version might read as follows:

> "In further research, the relation between a firm's adoption of IT framework and its number of failed IT investment projects can be empirically examined."

Answer (score -2):

You should use comma after *research* because is the main sentence of the paragraph.

Comment: I'm sorry but that makes no sense at all. Do you mean "the main subject of the sentence"?